# Flatlist show blank screen when we do fast scroll in react native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am showing video in flatlist but when I scroll fast it shows me blank screen for a while, after some time it shows proper content. I am using functional component.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
<FlatList  
  windowSize={100}
  refreshing={false}
  data={state?.ProductListByCategory}
  renderItem={CategoriesItemsRender}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
  onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
  keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
/>
```

I use a windowSize prop of the FlatList component with a value of 100.

```
 windowSize={100}
```

Answer (score 1):

you may want to look at this, these doc contains every thing to do to avoid blanc screen while scrolling a flatlist :

https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration

I would advise "windowSize" props :

> Bigger windowSize will result in less chance of seeing blank space while scrolling. On the other hand, smaller windowSize will result in fewer items mounted simultaneously, saving memory.

Comment: Yes I already follow optimizing flatlist but when I scroll more speedly it still shows me blank screen.

Comment: maybe try https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image if you have heavy images.

Comment: Yes I am using react-native-fast-image for server image and react-native-video for server video url already, I am showing image and video in both Flatlist.

Comment: windowSize props works

Comment: i have same issue  see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75037577/when-i-scroll-fast-in-contact-app-then-sometime-data-come-after-a-second-in-reac

Answer (score 0):

FlatList will only load content when its seeable, if you want to have it preloaded use a ScrollView instead.